# C++ STL algorithm equal

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, equals

One particularly useful standard algorithm is `std::equal`, which is defined as follows:

```
template <typename InputIterator1, typename InputIterator2>
inline bool equal(InputIterator1 start1,
InputIterator1 end1,
InputIterator2 start2)
{
    while(start1 != end1)
    {
        if(*start1 != *start2) return false;
        ++start1;
        ++start2;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The algorithm walks over the range defined by `[start1, end1)` and
`[start2, start2 + (end1 – start1))` and returns whether the elements in the range are equal. Notice that the algorithm is templatized over two different types of input iterators.

Why is this?

Comment: For you might want to compare the contents from different containers, as an example.

Answer (score 13):

Lets say you have a `std::list<int>` and `std::vector<int>` and want to see if they are equal.  If `std::equal` did not take different iterator types you could not use it since `std::list<int>::iterator` is not the same type as `std::vector<int>::iterator`.

This also applies to the same container type but storing different elements.  A `std::vector<int>::iterator` is not the same as a `std::vector<long long>::iterator` and so you would not be able to compare those either if it used the same type for both iterator pairs.

Comment: It's not just different containers that can be accommodated - you can compare e.g. `vector<int>` to `vector<double>`.

Answer (score 10):

So far you've gotten two answers that focus on containers. That's the wrong focus. The fundamental data abstraction in the STL is the **sequence**. A sequence is defined by a pair of iterators. Containers are one way of managing sequences, but they are not the only way. So, to give the **right** <g> answer:

`std::equal` compares two sequences for equality. There is no good reason to limit the application of the algorithm to sequences that have the same iterator type, so there is no such limit. The sequences may have different origins, and may refer to different value types.

For example, you might want to check whether the values represented in a file that holds a text represention of double values is identical to the content of a vector of integers stored in memory. The vector defines a sequence; you can get at its iterators with `begin()` and `end()`. The file defines a sequence; you can get at its iterators by opening the file with an `ifstream` and creating a pair of `istream_iterator<double>` objects. `std::equal` (and all the rest of the standard algorithms) will work just fine with these disparate sources of data and their different data types.

Answer (score 5):

It is templatized this way so you can pass either two iterators of the same type or two iterators with different types.

For instance:

```
vector<int> a; //some stuff
list<int> b; //some stuff
equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
/*
Here InputIterator1 is a vector<int>::iterator
and InputIterator2 is a list<int>::iterator
*/

vector<double> c; //some stuff
vector<double> d; //some stuff
equal(c.begin(), c.end(), d.begin());
/*
Here InputIterator1 is a vector<double>::iterator
and InputIterator2 is also a vector<double>::iterator
*/
```